# What is this plant in my garden and should I remove it?

Tags: identification

We've got a plant I suspect is unwelcome growing in our front garden. This is our first time having a garden, so before doing anything about this I thought I'd ask for advice. I'm looking to find out vaugly **what the plant is** and **if it should be removed** plus, any advice on removing it successfully, if that's the recommendation, since it looks like it's got a pretty hefty stem at the base.

Context: this is a brand new garden in front of a newly built house that the builders only laid and setup 2 months ago. We don't remember if this plant was in the garden when we were given the house, but what I do know is that it's now alarmingly tall (you can see it's height relative to the base of our kitchen window in one of the full images - so it's probably over a metre) and to me looks *suspiciously* like it's going to end up being some kind of horrible big weed thing.

Here's two shots of the full plant from two angles. As said, you can see how tall it is relative to he window in the first image...

*Click all images for full size version*

[image: Full length shot of plant from front]
[image: Full length shot of plant from rear]

And here's a close up of the leaves and base, in case it helps.

[image: Close up of leaves]
[image: Close up of plant pase]